# which method will be run before onSelectionChanged when replace text in a EditText

Tags: android, overriding, android-edittext, listener

I have 2 classes:

```
public class ContentEditText extends EditText {
    public ContentEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public ContentEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ContentEditText(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override   
    protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd)
    { 
        Log.e(TAG, "on selectoin changed");
    } 
}
```

and

```
 public class EditTextListener implements TextWatcher {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "on text changed");  
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "on text changed");  
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) 
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "on text changed");  
    }   
}
```

Then I used 2 above classes by this code:

```
ContentEditText et = new ContentEditText(this);
et.addTextChangedListener(new EditTextListener());
```

When I run the above code, I replace a text in the edittext by another text, I see `onSelectionChanged` always is run before `onTextChanged`, `afterTextChanged`, `beforeTextChanged`.

So my question is: are there any methods will be run before `onSelectionChanged` when replace text in a EditText, and can be overidden ?

Thanks!